# Calculate "x" (integer), if KO = KL = LP

Tags: geometry

[image]

My progress...

[image]
$\boxed{x+\alpha = 180-46 = 134^o} (I)\\
\triangle KLO:180^o -2\alpha+η = x + \theta \rightarrow \boxed{x = 180^o -(2\alpha + \theta)+η}(II)\\ (I) in (II) :134^o - \alpha = 180^o -2\alpha - \theta + η\rightarrow \boxed{\alpha+\theta - n= 46^o}(III)\\
\triangle NOL: \theta+η +180^o -2\alpha= 46^o\rightarrow \boxed{2\alpha -\theta - n=134^o }(IV)\\
I=IV : x+\alpha = 2\alpha -\theta -η \rightarrow \boxed{x = \alpha -\theta - η} (VI)\\
(III) + (VI): 2\alpha-2η=x+ 46^o\rightarrow \boxed{\alpha - η = \frac{x+46^o}{2}}(VII)\\
\boxed{x = 46^o -2\theta} (VIII`)$

more is missing to find an equação....

Comment: $\angle KLO\neq 180^o-2\alpha=\angle KLP$

Comment: @DanielMathias  ,,,   Answer: x = 45degrees

Comment: @DanielMathias   exactly, $ 180^o-2\alpha=\angle KLP $

Comment: Try this: $\frac{180-\alpha}{2}=\angle KLO\lt\angle KNO=46$

Comment: I still haven't been able to find the solution but I found one more relationship: $\alpha - 2\theta = 88^o$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $\triangle KLP$ we have $$2\alpha+\angle KLP=180\implies\alpha<90\\x+\alpha<x+90\\134<x+90\\44<x$$
From $\triangle NLO$ we have $$\angle KLO+\angle NOL=180-134\implies\angle KLO<46$$
And as I suggested in comment $$\frac{180-\alpha}{2}<46\\[2ex]180-\alpha<92\\180-92<\alpha\\88<a\\x+88<x+\alpha\\x+88<134\\x<46$$
Putting it all together $$44<x<46\implies x=45$$

Comment: @DanielMathias..excellent, you used the concept of inequality. I tried to find a relationship between the equations and got lost. Thank you very much